# How to formate database date field and separete date and hour?

Tags: reactjs, json, postgresql, date, datetime

i'm working in a react project and now I need to show two fields on screen (date and hour) from a database date value.

```
createdAt: "2021-12-07T00:03:19.474Z"
```

I need to show the fields like

```
Date: 07/12/2021
Hour: 03:19
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either explore the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and use its methods (such as `getHours`, `getMinutes`).

```js
const dateFromDB = '2021-12-07T02:22:30.929+00:00';
const date = new Date(dateFromDB);

const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();

const hours = date.getHours();
const minutes = date.getMinutes();

console.log(`Date: ${day}/${month}/${year}`);
console.log(`Hour: ${hours}:${minutes}`);
```

Or, if you can use external libraries / work with dates a lot, use a library that makes this a lot more convenient.

- [Luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon)
- [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

Comment: Thank you MarcRo!!! You are brilliant. You solved my problem very very fast and I appreciate you. Thanks!!!